# How does System.currentTimeMillis() get its time

Tags: time, jvm, system-calls

Is the method `System.currentTimeMillis()` implemented to make a system call to the underlying operating system in order to receive the current time?

I ask since as far as I know, the method runs pretty fast, and takes as little as 6 CPU clocks, but this doesn't make sense because system calls are known to be slow.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` does not usually require switching to kernel mode. OS provides a mechanism that allows reading current time from user mode by mapping corresponding kernel pages directly into application address space.

E.g. Oracle JDK and OpenJDK implementation of `System.currentTimeMillis()` on Linux calls glibc [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) function. This call accesses kernel data directly from user space by means of [`vDSO`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).